# How to prove that $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$

Tags: matrices

$A,B\in M_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field. Prove that $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$.

I know it's correct if $A,B$ are both invertible. But how to prove the general case? I think it can be proved by Cauchy–Binet formula, but there should be better approaches.

$A^*$ means the adjugate of $A$.

Comment: I think $^*$ is commonly used for adjoint...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The equality is an algebraic identity, so it suffices to prove it for $F = \mathbb{R}$. Use the fact that the entries of $X^*$ are continuous functions of the entries of $X$ and that the set of invertible $n\times n$ matrices is dense in the space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: What if $F$ is not a number field? Your method is of course OK if $F=mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @叶胥达 Ultimately this is an equality of polynomials having integer coefficients.  If it works over $\mathbb R$ then the coefficients of the polynomials must coincide, hence it works everywhere.

Comment: @ErickWong Thank you. That is what I meant by "algebraic identity." BTW, how does one type "@" with non-latin characters?

Comment: @CatalinZara Well, I just used @ followed by the autocomplete in the desktop browser interface.  But I imagine that copy and paste should also work?